# Can't see any of my FBJS callbacks when running on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm using a UIWebView to auth and make Facebook Graph API calls. To Log out, I'm trying to send this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
        FB.init({
            appId   : "01234567890..."
            status  : true,
            cookie  : true, 
            oauth: true,
            xfbml   : true
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            // nothing in here is ever called!!!
        }
</script>
```

but the response to getLoginStatus never gets called ... so my
question is is there a better way to log out? I heard some blogs
saying my developer facebook account had to match the domain of
my app. Is that the case? It's running in iOS though so
how can it match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get this working so I just used the Graph API from the facebook iOS SDK:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk